# Custom message from @Pattern not shown on a Double property

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I am trying to use JSR-303 bean validation.

I added the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I put `ValidationMessages_es.properties` and `ValidationMessages_en.properties` in `/WEB-INF/classes`.

This is the model:

```
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]", message="{not.a.valid.number}")
private Double price;
```

And this is the view:

```
<p:inputText id="price"
    value="#{inventoryMB.product.price}">
    <f:convertNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="0" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="price" />
```

When I put an invalid number I get this message from the validator:

```
form:price: 'ss' is not a number. Example: 99
```

My custom messages from the properties are not working. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing several concepts and it isn't entirely clear what exactly you want, so it's hard to provide the right answer.

First of all, the `@Pattern` works only on `String` properties. If you intend to allow `[0-9]` only, just use `Integer` or `Long` instead of `Double`. If necessary, use a [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) to not go lower than `0`. This way you can also get rid of the whole `<f:convertNumber>`. However, this way you can't validate as number by JSR 303 then. It's thanks to the strong typed nature of Java already impossible to set the property with a syntactically invalid number. The conversion error which you're facing is actually coming from JSF's `<f:convertNumber>` which is implicitly also already used with default settings when a `java.lang.Number` property is been used, such as `Double`, `Long` and friends.

Your best bet is to specify the conversion error message in JSF side. You can do by either specifying `converterMessage` attribute of the input field:

```
<p:inputText ... converterMessage="#{bundle['not.a.valid.number']}" />
```

Or by overriding the JSF default conversion error message via [`<message-bundle>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/2668602#2668602) with this key:

```
javax.faces.converter.NumberConverter.NUMBER_detail={2}: ''{0}'' is not a number. Example: {1}
```

If you really need to be able to validate it by `@Pattern` of JSR303 bean validation, then declare the property as a `String`. But this completely defeats the strong typed nature of Java.

Comment: I use Double value because the field in DB is stored as double. Is there a better way to validate Doubles or Integers? For example with omnifaces?

Comment: Your best bet is a custom JSF converter. You can validate the pattern on a string value before parsing and returning as double. OmniFaces offers no builtin facilities for this.

Comment: I've answered a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848675/need-fconvertnumber-to-throw-error/